using SUMIF with array as argument
I need to get the sum of a column for each unique value on another 2 columns independently. as in the following example:

I need the sum of "num" for each unique value in "mod" where the concatenation of "term" and "desc" are also not duplicate
The highlighted Range above has the expected result, but its using the range in column 10 which is an auxiliary column that cannot be used.
the formula from R2C10 is the following:
=INDEX(R2C4:R6C4;XMATCH(R2C8:R5C8;R2C2:R6C2 & " - " & R2C3:R6C3);1)

(It is using column 8 which must also be excluded but I can do it without it just fine in one go with a LET and UNIQUE. It's just harder to read)
What I need to do is change the range R2C10:R5C10 in the following SUMIF for the index formula above that generated the values in said Range, but when I do it I get the spill to the right with #VALUE!
=SUMIF(R2C10:R5C10;R10C1:R12C1;R2C1:R6C1)

I´ve seen some videos of people using SUMIF or SUMIFS with INDEX arrays as arguments, but I must be doing something wrong.
How should I proceed to do this?

You could try using the following formula:


• Formula used in cell B8
=SUM(TAKE(UNIQUE(FILTER(A$2:C$6,A8=D$2:D$6)),,1))


• Or using one single dynamic array formula:
=MAP(A8#,LAMBDA(x,SUM(TAKE(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:C6,x=D2:D6)),,1))))


Or, if the duplicate values have different num, then this should be a better alternative as far I think,,


=MAP(A8#,LAMBDA(x,
 LET(
     a, FILTER(HSTACK(B2:B6&" "&C2:C6,A2:A6),D2:D6=x),
     b, TAKE(a,,1),
     c, UNIQUE(b),
     SUM(VLOOKUP(c,a,2,0)))))



Thanks! Both work! I don´t quite undertand the dynamic array one or why the SUMIF wasn´t working with the INDEX inside it but worked fine when selecting the range, as i´ve seen people doing pretty similar things on some guides. But i will study the dynamic array functions you used when i have time to make sense of it.

@CarlosCezar arrays as criteria range for any IFs family functions won't work. But it works when used with in a criteria. If you look at the Microsoft Documentations it will show and instructed that the criteria range needs to be a range and never mentioned about array as well.

Also, for my Application of this code the num for the duplicate values shouldn't be different, but I appreciate the solution for a more general case! In this solution, it would take the first value of num in the case of duplicates as far as I understand, right?

@CarlosCezar absolutely correct. Since I had a confusion and there was no alternative data shown so I went ahead and proactively added the different formula which always accounts for the first occurrence of a duplicates

For the non-dynamic array solution, how can I do it if the columns aren't consecutive? The filter used A2:C6, but in my practical case I have more data in between those columns. Do i need to first create an array of those 3 together?

@CarlosCezar so for non-dynamic array version you would need auxiliary or helper columns, you won't be able to do it with one formula. and it will be complicated as far i see.

I made it work with one formula using CHOOSE({1,2,3};A2:AN;B2:BN;C2:CN) to get the columns in to one array.
I prefer the dynamic array one, but unfortunately I have to use data in a table, and I can't spill inside a table.

@CarlosCezar cannot spill inside a table because dynamic array formulas dont support structured references
